# Why is my nested text_area helper adding html tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, textarea

I have a text_area in a partial in a complex form that is called like so

```
<%= f.fields_for :notes do |notes_form| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'note', :locals => {:f => notes_form, :operation => f, :count => operation.notes.count} %>
<% end %>
<p><%= add_child_link "Add note", :operation_notes %></p>
```

and the partial looks like this

```
<% count ||= 2 %>
<div class='fields'>
<%= f.text_area :note_text, :rows => "4", :class => "notes" %>
<%= remove_child_link "x", f, count %>
</div>
```

There can be many notes on the form hence the add and remove child links.

The issue I'm having is that if I add a note with the text `'abcd'`, when I bring up the edit form I get `'<p>abcd</p>'`. If there are line breaks in the note it adds `<br />` tags. The text_area form helper seems to be using the simple_format helper but I have no idea why. Can anyone help as this is very undesirable behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah solved,

Earlier on the same page I was displaying the note and using simple_format to format it with

```
<%= simple_format note.note_text %>
```

It seems that simple_format is somewhat destructive as after this, a call to note.note_text always returns the formatted text. If I change the above to

```
<%= simple_format note.note_text.dup %>
```

then the note_text attribute is not altered and I get the appropriate results.

I will have to look more closely at simple_format but this really strikes me as undesirable behaviour.

*EDIT*

It looks like this has been corrected in Rails 3.1

Comment: Fantastic. I'd been looking for a solution to this for awhile. Simple format is indeed destructive in that it screws with your form text_area helper.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that you have something in your `Note` model that is processing the text. Check for callbacks in this model.

Comment: Nice thought but my note model is only
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :operations
  belongs_to :reviews
end