# Rails 3: Why does an indent appear when repopulating text_areas with line breaks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formatting, textarea, newline

I'm trying to program some forms that include `text_area` tags in Rails 3.1.3. Generally these text areas are filled with more than one paragraph (i.e. they include line breaks). If I save the text and display it with `simple_format`, the paragraphs display correctly, but if I repopulate the same form for editing, the format seems to add an indent after every line break. So, for example, if I input the following into the text area of the form:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

And I save it, the next time I load the form to edit the data, the text_area is populated with the following:

```
Item 1
    Item 2
    Item 3
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? The segment of the form view that displays this follows:

```
    <fieldset>
        <section class="field">
            <%= f.label "Títulos, seminarios, cursos" %>
            <%= f.text_area :titles_seminars_courses %>
        </section>
        ...
    </fieldset>
```

I'm not doing anything special when saving to the database (no gsub or anything), just directly saving the `'Item 1\r\nItem 2\r\nItem 3\r\n'` string. I'm using the same form for the initial creation and edition of this data.

Thank you in advance for any help with this issue.

EDIT 1:

The view that displays the data correctly is the following (but it's not in a text_area):

```
<section class="titles_seminars_courses">
    <%= simple_format(@academic_background.titles_seminars_courses, :class => "other_study") %>
</section>
```

EDIT 2:

```
<textarea cols="40" id="academic_background_titles_seminars_courses" name="academic_background[titles_seminars_courses]" rows="20">Item 1
        Item 2
        Item 3</textarea>
```

Comment: show how you are using simple_format.  simple_format (in versions below 3.2,  above 3.0) will alter the string formatted.

Comment: @RadBrad I'm using simple_format on another view which only displays this data (not editable), and it displays it correctly (no indents). This indenting problem only occurs in the form, where an editable text_area tag is populated with the instance field. Do you still need to see that other view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032187/why-is-my-nested-text-area-helper-adding-html-tags

Comment: @RadBrad I'm not using simple_format in the same view as this form, which seemed to cause the problem in the case you posted. Also, according to the answer, that issue was resolved in Rails 3.1. In my case, there are no `<p>` or `<br />` tags rendered; just the text with that formatting. I'll update the post with the rendered view.

Comment: The problem actually seems to be that these tags are not rendering. I guess I'd need a way to make the f.text_area statement use the simple_format helper somehow.

Comment: That's easy  f.text_area :titles_seminars_courses, simple_format(@academic_background.titles_seminars_courses)

Comment: I had tried that before, but I get the following error on that line: `Undefined method 'merge' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0xbc5ff5c>`. So I tried using `text_area_tag :titles_seminars_courses, simple_format(@academic_background.titles_seminars_courses)`. This doesn't give an error, but the tags are actually rendered as text in the textarea, not as HTML... and are indented as before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem seemed to be the mix between `html.haml` and `html.erb` views in the application. So either the `.erb` views are not properly rendered, or they don't play nice with the other `.haml` views. In mi case, for example, the application layout view is in haml, but the form was in erb.

Whatever the cause, the bottom line is that the text_area_tags don't render correctly in erb, but do in haml. So my workaround, although I know it is very hacky and not pretty, was to make a small partial in haml called `_text_area.html.haml` which renders just the textarea for a form:

_text_area.html.haml:

```
-if defined? options
    = f.text_area field, options
-else
    = f.text_area field
```

So every time I want to have a text_area tag in a form, I have to call a render like so:

```
<%= form_for @instance do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= render :partial => 'common/text_area', :locals => {:f => f, :field => :some_field_from_instance, :options => {:cols => 40, :rows => 10}} %>
    <%= render :partial => 'common/text_area', :locals => {:f => f, :field => :some_other_field} %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

This renders perfectly. That's why I think the problem lies with haml and its interpretation of indentation. If anyone has a better solution, please do let me know.

Comment: You are a genius. My layout is a haml file, but some parts of the application are erb. This bug still exists as of today, we currently use Rails 4.0.3 and haml 4.0.5. Many thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just a quick follow-up: Turning on ugly mode with `Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true` is a good workaround, in case anyone finds this question!

Answer (score 0):

For HAML, If you use:

```
 ~ f.text_area
```

instead of:

```
= f.text_area
```

it has the same effect as `Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true` and will preserve the whitespace in your saved text string, rather than trying to pretty it up.

read more in the docs [here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde)